# How to create reusable UDF in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I had implemented one [User Defined Function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) which parsed complex JSON and returned hundreds of fields to generate new table.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  PARSE_DATA(input STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT<field_a STRING,
  field_b STRING,
  field_c ARRAY<STRUCT<...>>,
  ...
  field_xxx STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
return parseData(input)
"""
  OPTIONS (
  library="gs://foo/bar.js"
);
```

Since most of JSON are quite similar, I had already implemented one JS UDF to return different schemas. My question is how could I reuse this UDF via changing **RETURNS STRUCT** to generate different tables?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to achieve. Do you have pseudo code in mind to demonstrate the idea?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment `BigQuery` doesn't allow you to create UDFs with generic return types. As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-javascript-udf-data-types), the `STRUCT` type must have its fields explicitly named.

[image]

I hope it helps